# how to call an dll file dynamically from code behind(.cs)

Tags: asp.net

i have  an  microsoft .office.interop.excel(dll) located  at an directory d:\abc.  now i do not want to add them  as an web reference in my projet   and  call them

rather  call the dll dynamically  from my code behind(.cs) 
is ther any way  we can do dynmically

anyhelp would be  great
 thank  you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will need to use reflection because if you don't add the assembly as reference it won't be known at compile time. Take a look at [LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) method.

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"d:\abc\microsoft.office.interop.excel.dll");
var someType = assembly.GetType("Namespace.Type");
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
someType.InvokeMember(... // the reflection pain goes on
```

Comment: hi,
Darin Dimitrov
 i have  did  the above method as   you told. now  how do i insert valued  from excel file to sqlserver 2005

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in `Assembly.Load()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I want to discourage you from doing that. It can definitely be done if read the dll into a byte[] and call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(byte[])`. However you will find that you can only work with the types of that assembly through reflection. Otherwise your code behind file will not compile. So if at all possible you should add a reference (not a web reference) to the dll.